# How to allow my customers to view different branches of a website

Tags: git, testing, preview

We use Git as our source control and I was wondering what the best way was to allow my clients to view each feature branch (as the website itself) for review and approval of the new feature. (we could have several different features in development for the client at any one time - all going live at different times)

Currently we have to create separate test sites for each branch. E.g.:

```
Master branch (live): www.lovelywebsite.com
dev branch: lovelywebsite-dev.mytestsite.com
new-homepage branch: lovelywebsite-new-homepage.mytestsite.com
new-feature1 branch: lovelywebsite-new-feature1.mytestsite.com
```

This method takes quite a bit of time to setup a new test site (inc db etc) each time we create a new branch. It also eats up our server resources. (some sites can be many GBs in size)

We need to be able to allow the client to view these features and approve them before we can merge into master and push live.

How do other people achieve this?

Comment: Consider automation. Use a CI server to do the heavy lifting

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox - not quite following you though...

Comment: When you clone a repository in the same file system, the new repository is hardlinked to the origin, which is very quick and cheap. You could then automate setting up virtual hosting from there.

Comment: Thanks but repos are not held on the same server as the site

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't a `git` question, just because you happen to be using `git` as your source control.  The problem would be the same no matter how you track your source code: you need to deploy your various features for testing.  There isn't a `git`-specific solution...

There are a few ways to look at the problem, but no one magic bullet.  In general I'd recommend looking at automated build/deployment tools.  (Can't recommend one specifically; too many variables about your project / technology stack.  But tools like Jenkins, TeamCity, Octopus Deploy, ...)  Some other thoughts:

*One Test Environment for All Features*

So I'm not saying that this is theoretically ideal, but as you asked how people have handled this in practice:

Many organizations just have a single test environment, and as features are ready to test they are merged into a single test-ready branch to be deployed to this environment.  Sure, maybe you have a homepage redesign and a new contact page both in the test environment, and one is going live before the other... but often organizations don't care.  With both deployed, either can be reviewed.

"But if they review the whole site, they'll see changes they don't expect."  Yes, and the more closely the changes overlap the more troublesome that *could* be.  (That is, it's one thing if one change is on this page and another on that page; another if one change modifies this page's content and another modifies its style; etc.)  But it boils down to a communication issue with the business/reviewers.

Not only is this often acceptable, it actually does have *some* advantages.  Because eventually you do need those features deployed together.  If you have the users test each of them individually, and the code interacts in some bad, unforeseen way when it's all merged together... well, that's another thing you should be testing for.  (And that, too, becomes a bigger issue the more the features overlap.)

It's one option.  It's simple.  Many organizations find it acceptable.

But maybe yours doesn't, so what else is there?

*One Test Environment At a Time*

Maybe you could deploy the most urgent feature, then once it's signed off deploy the next one.  Whether this is practical depends a lot on whether your UAT with the client typically invovles a lot of back-and-forth.  (If it does, you might consider adopting practices to mitigate that - more client engagement throughout the process.  But the process changes involved in that are a far broader topic, that mostly belongs under the heading "Agile development".)

If practical, this does two things.  Obviously it reduces the server resource issue since the several multi-GB sites needn't be deployed concurrently.  Also, because the deployment target is constant and you need only vary the branch from which to deploy, it makes it easier to set up automated build/deployment tools, which would reduce the time/effort overhead.

But again, maybe it doesn't suit your needs; what if you absolutely, positively, *must* have all versions available at once?

*Lighter-Weight Deployments*

Depending on your site technology, perhaps you could make the deployment process for each site less cumbersome.  This may do little for your server resources, but a few things:

It sounds like you're setting up a separate hostname for each site.  What if instead of

```
lovelywebsite-new-homepage.mytestsite.com
```

you used

```
lovelywebsite.mytestsite.com/newhomepage
```

So everything deploys to a single server (or farm), no per-branch DNS setup, maybe a lighter-weight setup for each variation.  Again, the details depend a lot on your site's technology, but it's possibly a thing you could look into.

OTOH, maybe you're deploying to physically distinct servers specifically to avoid over-taxing one server.  (And maybe you have metrics that support the need to do so.)  So what else have we got?

*Restructure the Project*

We're kind of running out of "easy" solutions.  It sounds like you have a rather large sites.  Perhaps at development/test time they could be split into a number of smaller, independently-deployable subsites, with the ability to configure all sections that aren't under test to defer to a "default site" that mirrors production?

The obvious problem with solutions like this, apart from the complexity and the need to develop project-specific techniques to divide the site up, is that the test site is not as much like the final running production site as it ideally should be - and those differences could create phantom errors or mask real errors.

Comment: Excellent response, thank you. While I was kinda hoping for a "sure use service x, it does all you want and more" I think I'm going to have to consider the options you list (notably the One Test Environment for All Features option) - My concern is that the database changes for feature A may conflict with database changes for feature B (although I could then mix in with your "Lighter-Weight Deployments" idea and have the DBs replicated per feature only then a widget for the client to chose the feature DB...).